# Qemu no init found (devtmpfs: error mounting -2)

Tags: linux, qemu, buildroot

Hi I am trying to run linux on qemu using buildroot. I spent a lot of time looking online for the right config options however despite multiple attempts I am still getting the same error. I do not understand why I am getting this: devtmpfs: error mounting -2.

This is the qemu command I used: cd buildroot/output/images && qemu-system-riscv32 -M virt -bios fw_payload.bin -kernel Image -drive file=rootfs.cpio,format=raw,id=hd0 -device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd0 -nographic

The is the output of qemu: https://pastebin.com/yW4FV0XD

This is my linux config:
https://pastebin.com/SaR1DFuq

This is my bootroot config: https://pastebin.com/5Gw82ekZ

I tried changing a lot of config options and yet no luck. I tried changing the config options and googling the issue. I tried recompiling multiple times. I don't understand is the issue with initramfs or devtempfs. This entire thing just seems really weird to me.

One of the stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569741/kernel-emulation-with-qemu) questions recommend adding -initrd initramfs when running it with qemu. However, I am not sure how to do that since initramfs is a part of my rootfs based on my config options. Any advice would be incredibly appreciated! Thanks!